# Php function stopping after 7th value

Tags: php

hi i have a function that gets Data from an ODBC connection

```
public function SageData() {
    $conn = odbc_connect('Data hub', '', '');
    if (!$conn) {
        exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[MACHINE], [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[cycletime]
FROM [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN]
WHERE ((([SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[MACHINE])='$this->name'));

";

    $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
    if (!$rs) {
        exit("Error in SQL");
    }

    while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {

        $this->SageCycle = odbc_result($rs, "cycletime");
    }
  //  var_dump($this->SageCycle);
    odbc_close($conn);
    return $this->SageCycle;
}
```

This function is part of a class below is the code to create a new object in the class, In the function the $this->name corresponds to the ZW01001 and so on numbers

```
Machinecycle("ZW01001", "ZW01001Percent", 0);
Machinecycle("ZW01004", "ZW01004Percent", 1);
Machinecycle("ZW01005", "ZW01005Percent", 2);
```

the function is called by another function in the class to turn the data in to a percentage i can use see below

```
public function GetM() {

    $q = $this->Cycle();
    $qq = $this->SageData();

    $this->M = $q - $qq;
  //  $this->P = $this->M / $this->sageData();

    if ($qq == 0) {
        $this->P = 0;
    } else {
        $this->P = $this->M / $this->sageData();
    }

    return round($this->P, 2);
}
```

The Values outputted by GetM are put in to an array, my problem is that when i run this i get the data for the first 7 out of 14 objects and this error for the rest of them

```
Notice: Undefined property: machine::$Cycletime in C:\Somepath\Datatest.php on line 104
```

Line 104 is this part

```
    return round($this->Cycletime, 2);
```

What i do not understand is why it is doing this after the first 7 and failing on the rest the data is there

to clarify there are 14 instances of the class and it works for the first 7 and then stops after those.

Here is the entire class for Machines It's a real mess but here it is www.pastebin.com/LMk2gvWG
This might help debug it When i echo the Sql i get this pastebin.com/13nufXYt for some reason 1-9 are are repeated but those are the ones that work it's the once that are not repeated that dont work

Comment: It seems to me that the variable `Cycletime` is not declared in your class blueprint, but is set somewhere. But for some reason in the 7th instance it isn't set, hence the error message. Could you post the code that is setting `machine::$Cycletime` as well? And a dump of the variables that affect this variable, on that specific time?

Comment: The only place Cycletime is used is in the code at the top of the question, and then i am calling the function to SageData() to get the values from it so i am not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code of class 'machine'? Maybe somewhere the variable is replaced by other class object.

Comment: You only get one _Notice_? I guess that maybe the data you query from SQL cause the problem. Because I use static number replace the return of each function, the program works well.

Comment: No i get 
Notice: Undefined variable: SageCycle in C:\Documents and Settings\jKirkpatrick\My Documents\xammp\htdocs\Datatest.php on line 106

7 times

Comment: This might help debug it  When i echo the Sql i get this 
http://pastebin.com/13nufXYt for some reason 1-9 are are repeated but those are the ones that work it's the once that are not repeated that dont work